# How to track how many times a button was clicked on my website

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I'm currently creating a website using HTML, CSS, JS, and Bootstrap and using Google Analytics to collect data about site visits. How can I track the amount of times a certain button in my website was clicked and where can I see this information in Google Analytics? Any help is greatly appreciated!

This is what I've tried so far:

```
function trackInstaButtonClick() {
  // Send an event to Google Analytics
  gtag('event', 'button_click', {
    'event_category': 'Button Clicks',
    'event_label': 'Instagram Button'
  });
}
```

This is in my `script.js` file that is linked to my HTML.

Comment: Your tracking code is correct. And you need to set an `onClick` function on your button:
`document.getElementById('button_id').addEventListener('click', trackInstaButtonClick);`
And try to view again the reports after a few days.

Comment: Adding on to @adampweb above, you could drop the `onClick` function and look at real time data in GA4 to see if it is being captured and not have to wait for the data to populate in reports after the daily refresh. You could also use debug mode in GA4: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7201382?hl=en